# Assign image to taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wanting to assaign an image to a few of taxonomy terms. I created a custom taxonomy 'payment'. Well I retrieved all terms using 
`$wpz_pay_icon = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'payment', array('fields' => 'names' ));`

I can display each term per post with

```
foreach ( $wpz_pay_icon as $icon ) {
echo $icon;
}
```

I would like the same output but instead of the text name, simply assign an image to the value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this plugin: [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/)

Comment: Thanks Peter. It took a little digging but it works great.